# When would this condition in deepToString evaluate to true?

Tags: java

I was looking at the method [Arrays.deepToString](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/f243173a188fc04f3883d975a368c6b71182f75d/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java#L4969) and could not understand the condition below.

```
  public static String deepToString(Object[] a) {
    if (a == null)
        return "null";

    int bufLen = 20 * a.length;
    if (a.length != 0 && bufLen <= 0) 
        bufLen = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(bufLen);
    deepToString(a, buf, new HashSet<>());
    return buf.toString();
 }
```

When would the condition  `a.length != 0 && bufLen <= 0` evaluate to true?

Comment: When `bufLen` overflows, for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `a.length` is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE / 20`, `bufLen` will overflow and become negative.

So the code sets it to the greatest possible integer value.

Answer (score 1):

It will return true only if `a.length` is very large so that `20 * a.length` can't fit in `int` data type. However, I'm not sure that this can ever happen.